# Laravel get size amount if not exist 0

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to make a list with all the available products and the amount per size like

```
 name     | size1  | size2  | size 3 | size4   | total
 ________________________________________________________
 t-shirt1 |   0    |    1   |    3    |   9    | 13
 t-shirt2 |   3    |    1   |    1    |   9    | 14
 t-shirt3 |   0    |    0   |    0    |   0    | 0
```

My `Product` model has a relation with `ProductSize` like:

```
public function sizeAvailable(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductSize');

}
```

My `ProductSize` has a relation with `Product` like:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

My `productSize` has a relation with `Size` like:

```
public function size(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Size');
}
```

The ProductSize model contains a value for amount.
So Im able to get all sizes for a product with the right amount, and im also able to get all products from a size. How could I create the list as in my example. Is it possible to use size as an index? so  I could do (pseudo code) to fill the `<td>` tags:

```
for(all products)
{
    if(product[somesize] not null)
      {{ product[somesize]->amount }}
    else
       0
}
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to set the amount in the `<tr>` of the table if there is for example 1 size (size3) and no others when I do `$product->sizeAvailable()` it will only contain 1 value (size3), so I need to place 0 under size1 but how can I check if size1 is not available for the product?
Or is there a better way to fill the table size amounts?

What I currently have:

```
 <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter table table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Product
            </th>
            @foreach($sizes as $size)
                <th>
                    {{ $size->name }}
                </th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach($products as $product)
                <tr >
                    <td>
                        {{ucfirst($product->name)}}
                    </td>
                    @foreach($sizes as $size)
                        <td>
                             HERE I NEED TO DO A CHECK IF $product HAS $size RETURN 0 ELSE RETURN ProductSize->amount
                        </td>
                    @endforeach



                </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I could make a function in product model like:

```
 hasSize($size)
 {
    $result = select from ProductSize where size = $size  

    if ($result = null)
       return 0;

    return $result->amount();
 }
```

But with this solution I have to run a query `products * sizes` times, if I have 1000 products and 20 sizes, that would meen 20.000 querys for one table.

```
____________________________
Relevant Database data
____________________________


products
-id           (primary key)
-name

sizes
-id           (primary key)
-name

product_sizes
-pr           (primary key)
-prodcut_id
-size_id
-amount
```

Comment: Have you toyed around with aggregates ([here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates) & [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)) for this problem Sven?

Comment: I must admit that a SQL join or even view based on that would've been a good fit, too - I still tried to provide an all-Laravel solution to show how far it can go.

Comment: is the `Relevant Database data` on the bottom complete? you mentioned tha ProductSizes model contains a value for `amount` - does the `product_sizes` table have this column, too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have manually built a [Many to Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for which Laravel already provides several useful features:

**1. Update Product model (add or replace existing relation):**

```
public function sizes()
{
    // many to many relation with intermediate table column
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Size', 'product_sizes')->withPivot('amount');
}

public function getTotalAttribute()
{
    // access pivot table directly and use sum aggregate
    return DB::table('product_sizes')->where('product_id', $this->attributes['id'])->sum('amount');
}
```

**2. Retrieve models (in controller) like this:**

```
$sizes = Size::all();
$products = Product::with('sizes')->get(); // eager load sizes
```

**3. Blade template:**

```
...
<td>
    {{ucfirst($product->name)}}
</td>
@foreach($sizes as $size)
<td>
    {{-- HERE I NEED TO DO A CHECK IF $product HAS $size RETURN 0 ELSE RETURN ProductSize->amount --}}
    {{-- check and retrieve by using Collection methods --}}
    {{ $product->sizes->contains($size) ? $product->sizes->find($size)->pivot->amount : 0 }}
</td>
@endforeach
<td>{{ $product->total }}</td>
....
```

---

After recreating your example with the changes above and a (very small) database seed I get:

```
Product     size1   size2   size3   total
T-shirt1    10      3       0       13
T-shirt2    5       0       0       5
```

---

- By default this solution only produces 3 queries due to [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). (Verify with [DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)) Each `total` calculation adds one query (unfortunately the Laravel query builder has no [aggregate methods](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#aggregates) for pivot tables).
- `contains()` and `find()` in the view traverse the prefetched collections - no additional queries here.
- You do not need the `ProductSize` model as it only houses a pivot table with an additional attribute (`amount`). See [Many to Many relationships and retrieving intermediate table columns](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).
- For convenience: if the `product_sizes` table is renamed to `product_size` and therefore follows Laravel's table naming convention the second parameter in `$this->belongsToMany('App\Size', 'product_sizes')` is not needed and may be written like this: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Size')`

> The [product_size] table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names.

Comment: @ somebody: provide a constructive comment if voting down as SO suggests - does not make much sense without it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use your table structure because I don't know it exact construction but I make for you an example.

I use only 2 queryes and not 20 000

Try it, make new database use dump

SQL dump

```
  # Host: localhost  (Version: 5.5.25)
  # Date: 2002-01-01 01:34:00
  # Generator: MySQL-Front 5.3  (Build 4.81)

  /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

  #
  # Structure for table "products"
  #

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
  CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  #
  # Data for table "products"
  #

  INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (1,'iphone'),(2,'Ls'),(3,'Samsung');

  #
  # Structure for table "size_name"
  #

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `size_name`;
  CREATE TABLE `size_name` (
    `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `size_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  #
  # Data for table "size_name"
  #

  INSERT INTO `size_name` VALUES (1,'1','2','color'),(2,'2','1','width'),(3,'3','3','height'),(6,'3','2','color'),(7,'2','3','width'),(8,'1','1','height'),(9,'1','3','color'),(10,'2','2','width'),(11,'3','1','height');

  #
  # Structure for table "size_value"
  #

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `size_value`;
  CREATE TABLE `size_value` (
    `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  #
  # Data for table "size_value"
  #

  INSERT INTO `size_value` VALUES (1,''),(2,'bluen'),(3,'green'),(5,'type2'),(6,'type3'),(7,'type4');
```

And now PHP

```
  <?php
  $bd_host="localhost"; 
  $bd_user="root";
  $bd_password="";
  $bd_base="newdatabase2";
  $con=mysql_connect($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_password); 
  if(!con) { echo 'error.'; exit; }
  mysql_select_db($bd_base, $con); 
  mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
  /* query1 get table rows caption */
  $q="select * from size_name group by size_id";
  $res=mysql_query($q);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $caption[$row['id']]=$row['name'];
  }
  // I limit to 3 products but you can change here, make loop
  $prod1='1';
  $prod2='2';
  $prod3='3';
  //here you need to change to work with all products
  $where=" where size_name.product_id='$prod1' or size_name.product_id='$prod2' or size_name.product_id='$prod3' ";
  /* query2 select size for your example */
  $q="select * from size_name left join (size_value) on (size_name.id=size_value.id ) $where order by size_id, product_id";
  $res=mysql_query($q);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  if(!isset($id) || $id<>$row['size_id']) $id=$row['size_id']; 

  /**/
  /* here nedd to make loop for all products youu need, I do for only 3 products */
  /**/
  /**/
  /*#1*/ 
  if($row['product_id']==$prod1) $characteristics1[$prod1][$id]=$row['value_name']; else
  /*#2*/
  if($row['product_id']==$prod2) $characteristics2[$prod2][$id]=$row['value_name']; else
  /*#3*/
  if($row['product_id']==$prod3) $characteristics3[$prod3][$id]=$row['value_name']; 
  /**/
  /**/
  } 
  ?>
  <table style="width:80%;border-spacing:0; text-align:center;">
  <tr style="background-color:purple;color:#FFF;">
  <td style="background-color:yellow; color:#999;"></td>
  <td>Product 1</td>
  <td>Product 2</td>
  <td>Product 3</td>
  </tr>
  <?
  foreach($caption as $key => $value) { ?>
  <tr>
  <td style="background-color:yellow;width:20%;"><? echo $caption[$key]; ?></td>
  <td style="width:20%;"><? if($characteristics1[$prod1][$key]!='') echo $characteristics1[$prod1][$key]; else echo ' 0 '; ?></td>
  <td style="width:20%;"><? if($characteristics2[$prod2][$key]!='') echo $characteristics2[$prod2][$key]; else echo ' 0 '; ?></td>
  <td style="width:20%;"><? if($characteristics3[$prod3][$key]!='') echo $characteristics3[$prod3][$key]; else echo ' 0 '; ?></td>
  <?
  } ?>
  </tr></table>
```